# Table with 1 of several FKs vs multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys, cascade

Consider the following 3 tables:

```
create table FOO (
    foo_index Numeric(38, 0)
        primary key clustered
        constraint foo_foo_index_nn not null
        identity(1,1)
)

create table BAR (
    bar_index Numeric(38, 0)
        primary key clustered
        constraint bar_bar_index_nn not null
        identity(1,1),
    foo_index Numeric(38, 0)
        constraint bar_foo_index_nn not null
        constraint bar_foo_index_fk references FOO(foo_index)
        on delete cascade
)

create table BAZ (
    baz_index Numeric(38, 0)
        primary key clustered
        constraint baz_baz_index_nn not null
        identity(1,1),
    foo_index Numeric(38, 0)
        constraint baz_foo_index_fk references FOO(foo_index)
        on delete cascade,
    bar_index Numeric(38, 0)
        constraint baz_bar_index_fk references BAR(bar_index)
        on delete cascade
)
```

Each `bar` is required to reference a `foo`. While it's not evident from the table creation, the intent is for each `baz` to reference a `foo` **or** a `bar`, but never both.

If you try to create the above schema you'll get this error:
`Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'baz_bar_index_fk' on table 'BAZ' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.`

Once SQL Server detects multiple cascade paths (in this case, the potential of a `baz` referencing both a `bar` and the `foo` the `bar` references and that 'foo` being deleted) rather than try to detect cascade cycles it just fails to be safe.

That wouldn't ever happen in actual use, though, since the plan is to only ever have one of the 2 foreign keys be non-null. Is there some way I can indicate that usage constraint to SQL Server so that it will allow both FKs to delete on cascade?

Comment: I ran into the same problem recently.  I don't think it's possible.  You can simulate this using DELETE triggers or by always deleting through a stored proc that does the check for you...  the latter is not always enforceable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a fault in your Design, your since it is not a typical foreign key constraint A Column Referencing back to A TABLE. you will not be able to have a foreign key constraint here, this is a more complex business requirement and a simple constraint like foreign key constraint wont be enough for this.....

### My Suggestions

1) Change NUMERIC(38,0) to INT, these all are identity columns and it will be incremented by one each time, I dont see the point of having this column as NUMERIC 38, which will be a 17 byte data type. INT will give you more than 2 billion rows in this table, bigint will give you  2^63 rows, let alone bigint limit if your table ever get anywhere near 2 billion rows you should consider Partitioning it not adding a bigger data type to add more rows, with such a huge table your performance will hit the rock bottom.

2) As you mentioned in Table BAZ one row will only reference back to either BAR or FOO I dont see the point to having two columns then, Add One column to reference back to either of the table and add another column smallest data type (a good candidate Bit data type) to identify which table a references to.

I would create you `BAZ` table something like this.....

```
create table BAZ 
(
    baz_index INT primary key clustered
              constraint baz_baz_index_nn not null identity(1,1),
    bar_Fo_index INT,
    Is_Bar       BIT     --<--  1 is bar 0 is foo      
)
```

### Cascade operation

For cascading you UPDATES, DELETES or INSERTS use stored procedures.

Comment: I guess I would use a trigger to make the deletion of the referenced `foo` or `bar` cascade to BAZ?

Comment: I would use a stored procedure, It kind of gives you the power of controlling it, triggers are another option but avoid them whenever you can, they are silent killers :)